# Generate only unique combinations when input contains duplicates

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, subset

I have a list with repeated elements, such as

`list = {a, a, b, c, c, c}`

and I'd like a list of the *unique* ways to choose 3 elements from it:

```
{{a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {c, c, c}}
```

Alas, "unique" means two different things at once in that sentence, and I can't figure out how to achieve both types of uniqueness simultaneously.

I could use `Permutations`, whose [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations) indicates regarding the input that

> Repeated elements are treated as identical.

But I will have many results that differ only by rearrangement, and I do not care about order:

`Permutations[list, {3}]`

```
{{a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, a}, {a, c, b}, {a, c, c}, {b, a, a}, {b, a, c}, {b, c, a}, {b, c, c}, {c, a, a}, {c, a, b}, {c, a, c}, {c, b, a}, {c, b, c}, {c, c, a}, {c, c, b}, {c, c, c}}
```

To eliminate the rearrangements, I could try using `Subsets` instead, but per *its* [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html),

> Different occurrences of the same element are treated as distinct.

As a result I get many duplicate results that I don't want due to the repeated elements of `list`:

`Subsets[list, {3}]`

```
{{a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {c, c, c}}
```

[Frustrated aside: I can't begin to imagine why Mathematica's permutations-generating function treats repeated list items differently than its combinations-generating function.]

I could eliminate the duplicates from either result, but either way, that still requires calculating the full list of nonunique results as an intermediate step, which I expect to be many orders of magnitude longer than the unique results.

Is it possible to get the result I'm after without having to cull a humongously longer list first to get there? The full problem I am working toward would be a list of 100 elements, ~25 unique elements with multiplicities ranging between 1 and 12, and desired subsets of 7 elements. (100 choose 7) is 16 billion, hence my interest in avoiding computing the full nonunique subset list.

Comment: Can you give ballpark estimates of 1) total length of the list, 2) number of distinct elements, 3) typical number of times an element is repeated; for your intended application?

Comment: The full problem I am working toward would be a list of 100 elements, ~25 unique elements with multiplicities ranging between 1 and 12, and desired subsets of 7 elements. (100 choose 7) is 16 billion, hence my interest in avoiding computing the full nonunique subset list. There are also several sub-problems that interest me if I can't get memory usage down enough to solve the full problem in one blow.

Comment: Why not use `DeleteDuplicates` on your input and called `Subsets` on that?

Comment: Thanks for the specifications, I've edited them into the OP :) My solution runs subsets of 7 elements in about two minutes on a list created with `Sort@RandomChoice[Range[1,25], 100]` whose largest `Tally` was 9. There were approximately 1.8 million subsets generated.

Comment: @b2m2a1 In the example I give in the question, 5 of the 6 unique subsets contain duplicate elements. It's not that I don't want duplicate elements in my subsets, just that taking, e.g., the first and second `a` shouldn't be counted as a distinct subset from taking the first and third `a`.

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I've added two improvements to my post that might be of interest :) Importantly, many approaches in the answers here, including my own and the accepted answer, spend a significant amount of their time converting from one representation (how many elements are selected of each kind) to the representation in the OP (list out the selected elements). This conversion is costly simply because there are so many subsets. OP should consider if this is necessary :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a quick-and-dirty, I'm sure there's more in it, busy with other things but will revisit when time permits.

```
fn[list_, len_] := Module[{t = Tally[list], u = Union[list]},
   Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[{u, #}]] & /@ 
    Select[Join @@ 
      Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[len, {Length@Union@list}, Range[0, len]],
     And @@ GreaterEqual @@@ Transpose[{t[[All, 2]], #}] &]];
```

Tested against what appear to be the current speed champions shows improvement:

```
list = Sort@Mod[Range[300], 17];
AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = subs[list, 8];] // First
AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = pickDistinct[list, 8];] // First
AbsoluteTiming[ans3 = fn[list, 8];] // First

Sort[Sort /@ ans1] == Sort[Sort /@ ans2] == Sort[Sort /@ ans3]
```

> 26.6541
>
> 29.7349
>
> 18.3133
>
> True

Comment: If you want speed, ciao usually provides! +1

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding the approach: You compute all possible unique multisets of the distinct elements, then reject the ones that exceed the actual multiplicities?

Comment: @thecommexokid - basically.

Comment: Basing a solution around `IntegerPartitions` was absolutely the way to go for me, so this one gets the Accept for my personal use-case.

Answer (score 9):

My take based on recursion. This approach will be good when the total number of elements is large compared to the number of distinct elements. The dependence on how many elements are picked (length of the subsets) is like that of Pascal's triangle, just like for `Subsets`.

Wrapper:

```
pickDistinct[list_, num_] := Block[
  {dist, count, elemsLeft, n, picked, result},
  {dist, count} = Transpose[Tally[list]];
  dist = Reverse[dist[[Ordering[count]]]];
  count = Reverse[Sort[count]];
  n = Length[dist];
  picked = ConstantArray[0, n];
  elemsLeft = Table[Total@Drop[count, i], {i, 0, n - 1}];

  result = Reap[pickDistinctRec[1, num]][[2, 1]];
  Table[
   Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[dist[[j]], result[[i, j]]], {j, 1, n}]
   , {i, Length[result]}
   ]
  ]
```

Recursion:

```
pickDistinctRec[pos_, leftToPick_] :=

 If[pos == n, picked[[pos]] = leftToPick; Sow[picked],
  Do[
   picked[[pos]] = m;
   pickDistinctRec[pos + 1, leftToPick - m]
   , {m, Min[leftToPick, count[[pos]]], 
    Max[0, leftToPick - elemsLeft[[pos + 1]]], -1}
   ]
  ]
```

For an example with 5 different symbols each occuring 10 times:

```
list = Sort@Mod[Range[50], 5];
AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = pickDistinct[list, 5];]
AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = Union@Subsets[list, {5}];]
```

> {0.002985, Null}
>
> {1.553072, Null}

so a factor 500 faster. Unfortunately I have 10.0.2.0 so I cannot compare to kglr's algorithm.

**UPDATE AND IMPROVEMENT:**

The following two tweaks give speedups relative to the original. The original is kept since it has been used for comparison in other posts.

*Method 1 (minor):*

Do the conversion to OP's subset format in-place instead of looping at the end. Also bail out from recursion as soon as there are no elements left to pick; this is important for the case of small subsets from list of many distinct symbols.

```
pickDistinct1[list_, num_] := Block[
  {dist, count, elemsLeft, n, picked, result},
  {dist, count} = Transpose[Tally[list]];
  dist = Reverse[dist[[Ordering[count]]]];
  count = Reverse[Sort[count]];
  n = Length[dist];
  picked = ConstantArray[0, n];
  elemsLeft = Table[Total@Drop[count, i], {i, 0, n - 1}];

  Reap[pickDistinctRec1[1, num]][[2, 1]]
  ]

pickDistinctRec1[pos_, leftToPick_] :=

 If[pos == n, picked[[pos]] = leftToPick; 
  Sow[Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[{dist, picked}]],
  Do[
   picked[[pos]] = m;
   pickDistinctRec1[pos + 1, leftToPick - m]
   , {m, Min[leftToPick, count[[pos]]], 
    Max[0, leftToPick - elemsLeft[[pos + 1]]], -1}
   ]
  ]

pickDistinctRec1[pos_, 0] :=

 Sow[Join @@ 
   ConstantArray @@@ 
    Transpose[{dist, PadRight[Take[picked, pos - 1], n]}]]
```

*Method 2 ((more) major):*

Don't use OP's subset format, but instead return **the number of times each symbol has been picked**. The function now returns two things: a list of distinct symbols, sorted from largest to smalles frequency, and a list of all the subsets in the format above. NOTE: Whether this is better or not depends a whole lot on how the subsets will be processed after, but that's for the user to decide.

```
pickDistinct2[list_, num_] := 
 Block[{dist, count, elemsLeft, n, picked, result}, {dist, count} = 
   Transpose[Tally[list]];
  dist = Reverse[dist[[Ordering[count]]]];
  count = Reverse[Sort[count]];
  n = Length[dist];
  picked = ConstantArray[0, n];
  elemsLeft = Table[Total@Drop[count, i], {i, 0, n - 1}];
  {dist, Reap[pickDistinctRec2[1, num]][[2, 1]]}
  ]

pickDistinctRec2[pos_, leftToPick_] := 
 If[pos == n, picked[[pos]] = leftToPick;
  Sow[picked],
  Do[picked[[pos]] = m;
   pickDistinctRec2[pos + 1, leftToPick - m], {m, 
    Min[leftToPick, count[[pos]]], 
    Max[0, leftToPick - elemsLeft[[pos + 1]]], -1}]]

pickDistinctRec2[pos_, 0] := Sow[PadRight[Take[picked, pos - 1], n]]
```

*Comparison:*

```
list = Sort @ Mod[Range[300], 17];
First @ AbsoluteTiming[ans = pickDistinct[list, 8];]
First @ AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = pickDistinct1[list, 8];]
First @ AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = pickDistinct2[list, 8];]
```

> 35.994123
>
> 16.761077
>
> 7.780696

Check:

```
ans === ans1
```

> True

```
Length[ans] == Length[ans2[[2]]]
```

> True

The approach is now comparable to ciao's:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[fnAns = fn[list, 8];]
Sort[Sort /@ fnAns] === Sort[Sort /@ ans]
```

> 20.015753
>
> True

and with

```
fn2[list_, len_] := 
 Module[{t = Tally[list], u = Union[list]}, 
  Select[Join @@ 
    Permutations /@ 
     IntegerPartitions[len, {Length@Union@list}, Range[0, len]], 
   And @@ GreaterEqual @@@ Transpose[{t[[All, 2]], #}] &]
  ]

First @ AbsoluteTiming[fnAns2 = fn2[list, 8];]
Sort[fnAns2] === Sort[ans2[[2]]]
```

> 8.756621
>
> True

Answer (score 6):

Here is a recursive version that is probably based on similar ideas as the one by @Marius, but looks a little simpler (which is subjective of course) and does not use any mutable state:

```
ClearAll[subs]
subs[list_List, len_] := Map[
  List @@ Flatten[#, Infinity, ll]&, 
  Flatten @ subs[ll[], Counts[list], len]
] 

subs[accum_, _, 0] := accum;

subs[accum_, counts_, left_] := 
  With[{fst = First @ Normal @ counts[[{1}]]},
    With[{elem = First @ fst, countLeft = Last @ fst},
        {
            (* Add element, update max count for it *)
            subs[
                ll[accum, elem], 
                DeleteCases[ReplacePart[counts, Key[elem] -> countLeft - 1], 0], 
                left -1 
            ],
            (* Skip element *)
            Replace[
                KeyDrop[counts, elem],
                {<||> -> Nothing, rc_ :> subs[accum, rc, left]}
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

It uses [linked lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/81) to accumulate the individual sublists, and at each step maintains a partially accumulated list, an association with remaining counts for different elements, and the total number of slots left.

Example:

```
subs[{a, a, b, c, c, c}, 3]

(* {{a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {c, c, c}} *)
```

It seems to be reasonably fast on larger lists, although is probably not the absolute fastest code:

```
list = Sort @ Mod[Range[50], 5];
subs[list, 5] // Length // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.005467, 126} *)
```

Comment: Having Leonid compare his method to mine is such an honor to me :) :) Sadly I cannot test it on my machine because 10.0.2.0 does not implement `Nothing`. Is there a quick workaround I can use? I tried `Replace[DeleteCases[KeyDrop[counts, elem], <||>], {rc_ :> subs[accum, rc, left]}]` but MMA still complains about "Part {1} of <||>" not existing...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer You can use `<||> ->  Sequence[]` in place of `<||> -> Nothing`, has the same effect and should work on earlier versions of MMA.

Answer (score 6):

An approach based on linear integer programming:

We are given a list of the form $\{a,a,b,c,c,c\}$, and a desired length of resulting multiplets $n$.  Generate the list of distinct elements $q_i$ and their multiplicities $m_i$.  Then solve the constrained system of equations
$$
\sum x_i = n  \\
0 \leq x_i \leq m_i
$$
for the $x_i$ over the integers.  Each of the resulting solutions for the variables $\{x_i\}$ will be correspond to a multiplet of the appropriate length, where the value of $x_i$ in each solution corresponds to the multiplicity of the element $q_i$ in that multiplet.

```
n = 3;
list = {a, a, b, c, c, c, c};

(* Create list of distinct elements *)
{distelements, counts} = Transpose[Tally[list]]
(* { {a, b, c}, {2, 1, 3} } *)

(* Create list of dummy variables x_i *)
variables = Array[x, {Length[distelements]}];

(* Open up a can of linear programming *)
soln = soln = variables /. 
  Solve[Join[{Total[variables] == n}, 
    Thread[0 <= variables <= counts]], variables, Integers]
(* {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}} *)

(* Extract the solutions *)
Flatten[Table[ConstantArray[distelements[[i]], #[[i]]], {i, 1, 
     Length[distelements]}]] & /@ soln
(* {{c, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, b}} *)
```

To see how this scales, I ran this code on a set of 100 randomly-chosen letters of the alphabet (26 distinct elements), with `n=7`.  Mathematica took about 20–30 minutes to return a list of ~3 million subsets on my not-that-powerful laptop.

Comment: Due to the wealth of responses, I didn't get a chance to play with this, but it's a delightful approach to the problem. I think it's the closest conceptual analogue to the clunky thing I would have tried to do if I hadn't had any of these answers to guide me. But much smarter.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[kMultiSubsets]

kMultiSubsets = Module[{lst = Sort @ #, k = #2, vars = Array[\[FormalX], Length @ #], 
     lengths = Tally[Sort @ list][[All, -1]]}, 
    Pick[lst, #, 1] & /@ (vars /. Solve[{Total[vars] == k, 
     And @@ Join[Thread[0 <= vars <= 1], 
       And[LessEqual @@ #, 0 <= Total@# <= #2] & @@@ 
        Transpose[{TakeList[vars, lengths], lengths}]]}, vars, Integers])] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {a, a, b, c, c, c};

kMultiSubsets[list, 3]
```

> ```
>  {{c, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {a, c, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, b}}
> ```

```
kMultiSubsets[list, 2]
```

> ```
> {{c, c}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {a, b}, {a, a}}
> ```

```
kMultiSubsets[list, 4]
```

> ```
> {{b, c, c, c}, {a, c, c, c}, {a, b, c, c}, {a, a, c, c}, {a, a, b, c}}
> ```

**Note:** This approach gives the desired result ***"without having to cull a humongously longer list***, ... but it slower than `DeleteDuplicates/Union`+ `Subsets` combination.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subsets[theSet={a, a, b, c, c, c}, {3}] // Union
```

Alternative,

```
Take[#, 3] & /@ Table[RotateLeft[theSet, i], {i, Length[theSet]}]
```

(*{{a, b, c}, {b, c, c}, {c, c, c}, {c, c, a}, {c, a, a}, {a, a, b}}*)

Don't forget to restrict count of element to max subset length (there were no need to do this for the given list. You may want to sort inner lists after construction.

Comment: "I could eliminate the duplicates, but that still requires calculating the full list of nonunique results as an intermediate step, which I expect to be many orders of magnitude longer than the unique results. Is it possible to get the result I'm after without having to cull a humongously longer list first to get there?"

Comment: the second approach does not give the full list of subsets. Take, for example, `theSet = {a, a, b, c, c, c, d}`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think in this case one needs in addition to construct some subsets of list of different elements.

Answer (score 1):

> {{a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, c, c}, {b, c, c}, {c, c, c}}

One way

```
 list = {a, a, b, c, c, c}
 r = Permutations[list, {3}];
 r1 = SortBy[#, ToString[#]] & /@ r;
 DeleteDuplicates[r1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Timings (any one is free to edit the timing and correct them as needed)

**Test 1**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
list = {a, a, b, c, c, c, d, e, f, g, h, m, n, z, k, r};
kMultiSubsets = 
  Module[{lst = Sort@#, k = #2, vars = Array[\[FormalX], Length@#], 
     lengths = Tally[Sort@list][[All, -1]]}, 
    Pick[lst, #, 1] & /@ (vars /. 
       Solve[{Total[vars] == k, 
         And @@ Join[Thread[0 <= vars <= 1], 
           And[LessEqual @@ #, 0 <= Total@# <= #2] & @@@ 
            Transpose[{TakeList[vars, lengths], lengths}]]}, vars, 
        Integers])] &;

pickDistinct[list_, num_] := 
  Block[{dist, count, elemsLeft, n, picked, result}, {dist, count} = 
    Transpose[Tally[list]];
   dist = Reverse[dist[[Ordering[count]]]];
   count = Reverse[Sort[count]];
   n = Length[dist];
   picked = ConstantArray[0, n];
   elemsLeft = Table[Total@Drop[count, i], {i, 0, n - 1}];
   result = Reap[pickDistinctRec[1, num]][[2, 1]];
   Table[Join @@ 
     Table[ConstantArray[dist[[j]], result[[i, j]]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 
     Length[result]}]];
pickDistinctRec[pos_, leftToPick_] := 
 If[pos == n, picked[[pos]] = leftToPick; Sow[picked], 
  Do[picked[[pos]] = m;
   pickDistinctRec[pos + 1, leftToPick - m], {m, 
    Min[leftToPick, count[[pos]]], 
    Max[0, leftToPick - elemsLeft[[pos + 1]]], -1}]]
```

Now

```
RepeatedTiming[
 res = SortBy[#, ToString[#]] & /@ Permutations[list, {4}];
 DeleteDuplicates[res];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RepeatedTiming[
 kMultiSubsets[list, 4];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 RepeatedTiming[Union[Subsets[list, {4}]];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 RepeatedTiming[pickDistinct[list, 4];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Test 2**

```
list = {a, a, b, c, c, c, d, e, f, g, h, m, n, z, k, r, k, l, j, x, y,
    t, w, q, b, b, b, z};


RepeatedTiming[
 res = SortBy[#, ToString[#]] & /@ Permutations[list, {5}];
 DeleteDuplicates[res];]

 (*9.26*)

RepeatedTiming[
 kMultiSubsets[list, 5];]

 (*4.666*)

RepeatedTiming[Union[Subsets[list, {5}]];]

(*0.0513*)


RepeatedTiming[pickDistinct[list, 5];]

(* 0.916 *)
```

Comment: "I could eliminate the duplicates, but that still requires calculating the full list of nonunique results as an intermediate step, which I expect to be many orders of magnitude longer than the unique results. Is it possible to get the result I'm after without having to cull a humongously longer list first to get there?"

Comment: Nasser, the last method would not generate the full list of subsets b/c it only takes 5-subsets of consecutive elements.

Comment: @kglr I am a little lost between all these methods :)  Please feel free to edit the timing part of my post and fix as needed.

Comment: I also think that the rotation works in case of 3. Otherwise, probably you in addition need to generate some subsets of lists for rotation.